# checking if value is nil and replacing it with empty string in NSdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am not an iOS developer, rather a rn developer who is picking objective c.

I have, an NSdictionry which looks like this

```
NSDictionary *selfInfo = @{
    @"id": selfPartcipant.id,
    @"name": selfPartcipant.name,
    @"picture": selfPartcipant.picture,
    @"audioEnabled": @(selfPartcipant.audioEnabled),
    @"videoEnabled": @(selfPartcipant.videoEnabled),
    @"isPinned": @(selfPartcipant.isPinned)
};
```

Here, `selfPartcipant.name` or `selfPartcipant.picture` can be nil (which would code to break). I want to put empty string when the value is nil.

Equivalent in javascript should be something like this

```
const a = {
  name: selfPartcipant.name || '', 
  picture: selfPartcipant.picture || '', 
  ...other properties
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Although Swift has a nil-coalescing operator `??`, Objective C does not, so your best bet is to use the ternary operator like so:

```objectivec
NSDictionary *selfInfo = @{
    @"id": selfPartcipant.id,
    @"name": selfPartcipant.name ? selfPartcipant.name : @"",
    @"picture": selfPartcipant.picture ? selfPartcipant.picture : @"",
    @"audioEnabled": @(selfPartcipant.audioEnabled),
    @"videoEnabled": @(selfPartcipant.videoEnabled),
    @"isPinned": @(selfPartcipant.isPinned)
};
```

Fair warning, this is the most Objective C I've ever written, so no guarantees that if you copy and paste this it will work, but the idea should be solid.